# Is possible to use Dynamic Opengraph meta with ReactJS only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem is when i change the OG Meta with ReactJS, the crawlers dont pick up the change, most of them dont render Javascript. So it must be done in SSR but I have no idea if it can be done in React, and if not, how?

Tried using React-Helmet, changing directly the DOM....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.